# How to run dwarf fortress on mac

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image: The folder]I just downloaded both of the newest versions of dwarf fortress for mac onto my 2008 Imac from the Bay 12 Games website and an application I didn't even know existed called Archive Utility expanded it into a folder that is unplayable. How do I download and play it?

Comment: What do you mean by "both of the newest versions"? What do you mean by "a folder that is unplayable"?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer the 64 bit and the 32 bit versions, and the folder has all the resources in it but no way to play it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [game wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Installation#Mac), you need to execute the launch script called `df`.

> To start the game execute the launch script "df".  Launching
>   "dwarfort.exe" by itself will not work

Also:

> On OS X 10.8 and above, you will need to download XQuartz to run Dwarf Fortress, which is no longer bundled with OS X by default.

And:

> On OS X 10.11 and above, you will need to update the SDL library

(Download links for the libraries are available on the [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Installation#Mac))

---

Archive utility is a program that decompress archives so you can access them. Archived file mostly have the .zip, .tar.tz extensions. In this case, the files where in a .tar.bz2 archive. So when the programm launched , it did not expand it into an unplayable folder, it gave you access to those file in an easier, uncompressed way.

Comment: It's most likely in an unplayable state until extracted.

Comment: @Fambida I got it to work, but it is uber complicated. The main slogan is 'Losing is fun'

Answer (score 0):

1. open terminal.
2. navigate to your df_osx directory. ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547730/how-to-navigate-to-to-different-directories-in-the-terminal-mac )
3. now that you are in the dwarf fortress directory in terminal type `./df` and press enter. this runs the file named 'df' inside the current directory './'.